# Executing oracle procedure without parameter

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace PROCEDURE emav_input_check
   (last_bus_day IN DATE, price_date IN DATE, o_param OUT NUMBER)
AS
bbg_yest       NUMBER;
bbg_today      NUMBER;
drates_yest    NUMBER;
drates_today   NUMBER;
equity_yest    NUMBER;
equity_today   NUMBER;
index_yest     NUMBER;
index_today    NUMBER;
retval         INTEGER;
retval1        INTEGER;
retval2        INTEGER;
retval3        INTEGER;
retval4        INTEGER;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_today    
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');


SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_yest
FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
WHERE     asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy')         
AND currency_code IN (' USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ')
AND TERM_WEEKS = 0;

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO drates_today
FROM pm_own.deposit_rates
WHERE     asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
AND currency_code IN (' USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY ');

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_yest
FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO equity_today
FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_EQUITY
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');


SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_yest
FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

SELECT COUNT (*) INTO index_today
FROM pm_own.BDVD_FORECAST_INDEX
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('price_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

IF bbg_yest != 0
THEN
SELECT ( (bbg_today - bbg_yest) * 100) / bbg_yest INTO retval1
FROM DUAL;
ELSE
retval1 := 0;
END IF;

IF drates_yest != 0
THEN
SELECT ( (drates_today - drates_yest) * 100) / drates_yest INTO retval2
FROM DUAL;
ELSE
retval2 := 0;
END IF;

IF equity_yest != 0
THEN
SELECT ( (equity_today - equity_yest) * 100) / equity_yest INTO retval3
FROM DUAL;
ELSE
retval3 := 0;
END IF;

IF index_yest != 0
THEN
SELECT ( (index_today - index_yest) * 100) / index_yest INTO retval4
FROM DUAL;
ELSE
retval4 := 0;
END IF;


retval := 0;

IF retval1 < 0 AND ABS (retval1) > 20
THEN
retval := 1;
ELSIF retval2 < 0 AND ABS (retval2) > 20
THEN
retval := 2;
ESIF retval3 < 0 AND ABS (retval3) > 20
THEN
retval := 3;
ELSIF retval4 < 0 AND ABS (retval4) > 20
THEN
retval := 4;
END IF;

o_param := retval;
END;
```

The code shown above is the procedure. When I execute it as-

```
declare
return_val number;
BEGIN
pm_own.emav_input_check(TO_DATE('05/19/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE('05/20/2014','MM/DD/YYYY'),return_val);
dbms_output.put_line(return_val);
END;
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error report:

ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
ORA-06512: at "PM_OWN.EMAV_INPUT_CHECK", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 4
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.
```

Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: What you do in your selects is wrong.
`WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');`
you try to cast the string 'last_bus_day' to a date, which is impossible of course.
I guees you need to remove the quotes.

Comment: why wrong -i think it works fine when executed as part of the procedure
?

Comment: You're calling it with a date already. You're passing TO_DATE('05/19/2014','MM/DD/YYYY') as the first param, and then trying to convert that again. Shouldn't you just be passing '05/19/2014', or not converting it in the function too?

Comment: @user3488955 'last_bus_day' is a constant string, whereas "LAST_BUS_DAY" is the name of a column (should be in uppercase!)
It depends on what quotes you use
UPD: what i wrote is nonsence, i didnt quite pay attention to what your case is, i am sorry. But still you should remember that quotes are different in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

you problem is in how you use your INCOMING parameters. Here is your code:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

'last_bus_day' is a constant string. Oracle tries to get mm (month as a number) out of it and fails.

your parameter: last_bus_day IN DATE

Therefore you don't need any more conversions:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
WHERE asof_date = last_bus_day;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
WHERE asof_date = TO_DATE ('last_bus_day', 'mm/dd/yyyy');
```

These are **not** valid queries. The `to_date` function expects a string representing a date, and a format string that says what format the first parameter is. `Last_bus_day` does not match `mm/dd/yyyy` so it fails. An example of a matching string would be `05/19/2014`.

Since your incoming parameter is a date, you should change your queries to be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO bbg_yest
FROM Crd_Own.Bbg_Oiv v
WHERE asof_date = last_bus_day;
```

because you don't need to convert the string to a date, then to a date again.

Comment: Thanks mason...and every one who answered .

Comment: Now I have one more question on that,trying to call above procedure from shell script -price_date="05/20/2014"
  last_bus_day="05/19/2014"
  ORAPWD=`cat /appl/${ENV_BASE}data/data/U/control/.xfile_svc_op`


    model_check=`sqlplus -s` <<....END
    svc_op/${ORAPWD}@${ORACLE_SERVER}
    var return_val number;
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set pagesize 0
    execute PM_OWN.emav_input_check(TO_DATE($last_bus_day,'MM/DD/YYYY'),TO_DATE($price_date,'MM/DD/YYYY'),:return_val);
    print return_val;
....END
echo $model_check

Comment: @user3488955 You should post that as a new question.